# rgba fillStyle with alpha does not get fully opaque if applied multiple times

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I stubled upon a weird problem. The following code results in making the image fade away because it's overdrawn by a semi-opaque rect over and over again.

But at least at the 10th  iteration of `draw();` the image should be completely overdrawn, because the rect should be fully opaque by then, right? But it actually never disappears completely.

This effect is worse on Chrome than it is on Firefox. But beware: bad screens may hide this faulty behaviour =)

I also made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bvRt3/1/) on jsFiddle.

```
$(function () {
var canvas = $("#mycanvas"),
    ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d"),
    imgUrl = "http://it-runde.de/dateien/2009/august/14/25.png";


var image = new Image();  
image.src = imgUrl ;  
$(image).load(function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
    draw();
});

function draw() {        
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
    setTimeout(draw, 100);
    
}    
});
```

The effect one may want to achieve is that, say an object is moving all over the canvas, and the already drawn positions get overdrawn only slightly so after-glow of after-fade effect. But this result is just fugly.

So is there any solution to this?

Comment: Remember that canvas works without "remembering" the previous state. So an alpha of `0.1` does not mean that after 10 times you've made it fully opaque, but rather the opacity will be `(1 - 0.1) * (1 - 0.1) * ...` which will indeed never reach `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the rectangle is only 10% opaque, the result of drawing it over the image is a composite of 90% of the image and 10% white. Each time you draw it you lose 10% of the previous iteration of the image; the rectangle itself does not become more opaque. (To get that effect, you would need to position another object over the image and animate its opacity.) So after 10 iterations you still have `(0.9^10)` or about 35% of the original image. Note that rounding errors will probably set in after about 30 iterations.

Comment: I still don't get it. Is this some internal image-processing-calculation? It's illogical to me. If I say in Photoshop position 10 layers with each 10% opacity over some content, the layers will completely cover it. This would also apply in real life, wouldn't it? I mean, I understand your answer, but why is that so? According to your explanation I would practically place an image with 100% opacity and sustract 10% of it's current opacity per iteration, but that's not what's happening here ... =( and: No the image does not disappear after 30 iterations. It stays there, grayed out.

Comment: think of it as reducing the amount of transparency by 10% with each new layer. After one layer, you have reduced 100% to 90%. The second layer reducing the remaining 90% by 10%, so by only 9%. Now you are at about 81%. The third layer would reduce the 81% by 8.1% leaving you with about 72.9%, etc....

Comment: @mizwo Perhaps an analogy will help: if you buy something that is 10% off, and you have a 10% staff discount, you do NOT get 20% off the original price, you only get 19%!

Comment: I'm having also this same problem (using processing.js), if I overlay the background layer with let's say 90% opacity on a canvas, the scene will never get to be covered fully by that layer. But why's that? I mean, even though you always get only 90% of the new image, after doing this an infinite times (iterations -> oo) you should still get the canvas 100% covered... How to fix those rounding errors (so the function actually converges to 0 in not-so-many steps) ?

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old but I don't think the previously accepted answer is correct. I think this is happening as a result of pixel values being truncated from float to byte. In Windows 7 running Chrome version 39.0.2171.95m, after running your fiddle for a while, the image is still visible but only lightly, and doesn't appear to be changing any more. If I take a screenshot I see the following pixel values on the image:

> (246, 246, 246)

When you draw a rectangle over it with rgba of:

> (255, 255, 255, 0.1)

and apply alpha blending using the default compositing mode of source-over, before converting to a byte you get:

> (255 * 0.1 + 246 * 0.9) = 246.9

So you can see that, assuming the browser simply truncates the floating point value to a byte, it will write out a value of 246, and every time you repeat the drawing operation you'll always end up with the same value.

There is a big discussion on the issue at this blog post [here](http://rectangleworld.com/blog/archives/871).

As a workaround you could continually clear the canvas and redraw the image with a decreasing globalAlpha value. For example:

```
    // Clear the canvas
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width(),canvas.height());

    // Decrement the alpha and draw the image
    alpha -= 0.1;
    if (alpha < 0) alpha = 0;
    ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
    console.log(alpha);
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 256, 256);
    setTimeout(draw, 100);
```

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1vx65gh3/).

Answer (score 0):

The reason was perfectly stated before. It is **not possible to get rid of it** without clearing it and redrawing it like @Sam already said.

What you can you do to compensate it a bit is to set `globalCompositeOperation`.

There are various operations that help. From my tests I can say that `hard-light` works best for dark backgrounds and `lighter` work best for bright backgrounds. But this very depends on your scene.

An example making trails on "near" black

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'hard-light'
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(20,20,20,0.2)' // The closer to black the better
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over' // reset to default value
```

Comment: it is possible to get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to manipulate the pixel data with ctx.getImageData and ctx.putImageData.

Instead of using ctx.fillRect with a translucent fillStyle, set each pixel slightly to your background colour each frame. In my case it is black, which makes things simpler.

With this solution, your trails can be as long as you want, if float precision is taken into account.

```
function postProcess(){
  const fadeAmount = 1-1/256;
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
  for (let x = 0; x < w; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < h; y++) {
      const i = (x + y * w) * 4;
      imageData.data[i] = Math.floor(imageData.data[i]*fadeAmount);
      imageData.data[i + 1] = Math.floor(imageData.data[i + 1]*fadeAmount);
      imageData.data[i + 2] = Math.floor(imageData.data[i + 2]*fadeAmount);
      imageData.data[i + 3] = 255;
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const w = window.innerWidth;
const h = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;
const cs = createCs(50);
let frame = 0;
function init(){
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h)
  loop();
}
function createCs(n){
  const cs = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cs.push({
      x: Math.random()*w,
      y: Math.random()*h,
      r: Math.random()*5+1
    });
  }
  return cs;
}
function draw(frame){
  //no longer need these:
  //ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)'
  //ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h)
  ctx.beginPath();
  cs.forEach(({x,y,r}, i) => {
    cs[i].x += 0.5;
    if(cs[i].x > w) cs[i].x = -r;
    ctx.moveTo(x+r+Math.cos((frame+i*4)/30)*r, y+Math.sin((frame+i*4)/30)*r);
    ctx.arc(x+Math.cos((frame+i*4)/30)*r,y+Math.sin((frame+i*4)/30)*r,r,0,Math.PI*2);
  });
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  //only fade every 4 frames
  if(frame % 4 === 0) postProcess(0,0,w,h*0.5);
  //fade every frame
  postProcess(0,h*0.5,w,h*0.5);
  
}
//fades canvas to black
function postProcess(sx,sy,dw,dh){
  sx = Math.round(sx);
  sy = Math.round(sy);
  dw = Math.round(dw);
  dh = Math.round(dh);
  const fadeAmount = 1-4/256;
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(sx, sy, dw, dh);
  for (let x = 0; x < w; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < h; y++) {
      const i = (x + y * w) * 4;
      imageData.data[i] = Math.floor(imageData.data[i]*fadeAmount);
      imageData.data[i + 1] = Math.floor(imageData.data[i + 1]*fadeAmount);
      imageData.data[i + 2] = Math.floor(imageData.data[i + 2]*fadeAmount);
      imageData.data[i + 3] = 255;
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, sx, sy);
}
function loop(){
  draw(frame);
  frame ++;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
init();
```

```css
canvas {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"/>
```