# HTML5 Canvas stacking images with drawImage() doesn't converge to correct color?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a drawing app with HTML5 canvas. To paint on the main canvas, I call drawImage() and paste the contents of a separate canvas that contains the brush image to the mouse position.

I can set the opacity of the brush canvas, and when you draw you can clearly see the instances stack and blend together, as they should. The problem arises when opacity is set to something low, like 0.01. You can scribble in one spot for a while, but it will never fully converge to the brush color. With a brush color of #000000 it will stop stacking at #2a2a2a.

Is there anything I can do about this? Here's an example app.

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #canvas1 {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }

        #canvas2 {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas1" width="300" height="300">
    </canvas>

    <canvas id="canvas2" width="20" height="20">
    </canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var elem1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var elem2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
        var context1 = elem1.getContext("2d");
        var context2 = elem2.getContext("2d");

        var drawing = false;

        init();

        function init() {
            //draw brush
            var alpha = 0.01;    //opacity of the brush
            context2.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, " + alpha + ")";
            context2.beginPath();
            context2.arc(10, 10, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
            context2.closePath();
            context2.fill();

            elem1.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){startdraw()});
            elem1.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){enddraw()});
            elem1.onmousemove = draw;
        }

        function startdraw() {
            drawing = true;
        }

        function enddraw() {
            drawing = false;
        }

        function draw(ev) {
            if(drawing) {
                context1.drawImage(elem2, ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft - 10, ev.pageY - this.offsetTop - 10);
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this will help, but take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895306/rgba-fillstyle-with-alpha-does-not-get-fully-opaque-if-applied-multiple-times I still feel like it should *coverge* to the color you want, even if it never completely reaches it. This is odd..

Comment: Also, the alpha value seems to be rounded to the nearest 255th... not sure if that's a problem. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/p0q4ne8e/